# Как обработать ошибку через try except

Tags: python

Возникла проблема, что у ошибки нет конкретного названия, по типу `ZeroDivisionError`, но надо как-то отсеять эту ошибку.
Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/http_list.py", line 35, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url, params=params, proxies=proxyDict)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 309, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 199, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 450, in proxy_from_url
    return ProxyManager(proxy_url=url, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 401, in __init__
    raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
```

Comment: Вон же в самом конце - ProxySchemeUnknown

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/http_list.py", line 36, in <module>
    except ProxySchemeUnknown:
NameError: name 'ProxySchemeUnknown' is not defined`

Comment: @AimBot Это исключение из библиотки urllib3 https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/exceptions.py#L228 . Чтобы использовать его, нужно сначала импортировать, видимо. Попробуйте `from urllib3.exceptions import ProxySchemeUnknown`

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib3.exceptions import ProxySchemeUnknown

try:
    ...
except ProxySchemeUnknown as e:
   ...
```